# Calculate the 15 min time bin the current time falls into using go

Tags: go, machine-learning, time

So I am unaware on how to calculate the 15 min time bin for the current time.
A day has 1440 minutes. So 96 - 15 min bins. So how can i calculate the time bin in golang?

```
func getCurrentMinutes(current time.Time) (int, error) {
   min, err := strconv.Atoi(current.Format("04"))
   if err != nil {
      return 0, err
   }
   return min, nil
}
func GetTimeBin(current time.Time, binDuration float64) float64 {
     min, _ := getCurrentMinutes(current)
     bin := float64(min) / binDuration
     return math.Ceil(bin)
}
```

The above implementation I have done is wrong as I am considering 15 min bins for an hour. I need to find the 15 min bin for the current time in the context of the day.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "A day has 1440 minutes." This is false unless you can guarantee that all your time values are in UTC, and even then you still have consider [leap seconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working example I came up with.

```
func GetTimeBin(current time.Time, binDuration float64) float64 {
  hours := current.Hour()
  min := current.Minute() + hours*60
  bin := float64(min) / binDuration
  return math.Ceil(bin)
}
```